# Datatables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined when using Buttons Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to initialize my table as:

```
var table = $("#table-id").DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": "8%", 
        "targets": 0
    }],
    'bSort': false,
    bPaginate: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
});
```

But I'm getting an error on Chrome's console that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined at dataTables.buttons.min.js:17

Comment: Note you're missing a `}` - although I assume that's just a typo otherwise you'd be seeing a different error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was just a typo when asking this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the appropriate plug-in to include the buttons. Take into account that datatables buttons "are not built into the core, but rather than be included as and when you need them" ([buttons doc](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/)). 
Hence, I would suggest you to either you use the download builder to customize your lib, or include them in separate files. I.e., the following libs are included in the buttons example:

- //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
- //cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js
- //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js
- //cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js
- //cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js
- //cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js
- //cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.print.min.js

Also, you will need the following dom modifier:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
```

Working jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jufjn9ux/